# Quarry block sunken firepit

Tags: landscaping, retaining-wall, backyard, fire-pit, limestone

I want to put limestone blocks 2x2x5’ for seats in a 10x12, 4’ deep fireplace area, I rented a digger and dig a good amount and plan to put 6” of bass or minus then the blocks around the pit.. will it sink over time?

I need it to drain and stay put right?

Comment: Hmm not sure how much depth you'd need here, but for strong bases for heavy stuff you lay gravel in 3" "lifts" and pack each lift with a packer before adding the next.  A properly packed lift feels hard like you're standing on concrete.  More lifts and more packing give more resistance to sinkage.  I definitely wouldn't think about less than 2 3" lifts, but  I'd consider more.  Nature of the gravel provides drainage and can be connected to weeping tile if you wish.

Comment: Well, yes, I presume you "need it to drain and stay put". Are you asking if you need _drainage_ in order for it to stay put? Please feel free to [edit] your post to clarify that bit. Also, are those blocks 2' x 2' x 5'? They're _mighty_ big and heavy. I'm no expert by any means, but I'd think that 6" of gravel may not be enough to support that - I'll let others with more experience chime in, though.

Comment: 6” is a lot of rock when compacted. I use 3/4- in my horse stalls and even our big boy ~1800 lbs doesn't have problems with 6” and a 1” rubber mat over that, your soil conditions could require more or not even need an inch it all depends on what is there.